# how to remove images and span dynamcially?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading images with span text dynamically inside a div.after this trying to remove specific uploaded images with its span text using below code,

```
 var images = document.getElementsByClassName('imgclass'); 
   for (var j = 0, leng = images.length; j < leng; j++) {
        images[j].onclick = RemoveImage;
    }

function RemoveImage() {

         alert("here");
        // var imagename = $(this).attr("src");
        // alert(imagename);
         $(this).remove();
         $(this).find('span').remove();
        //$(this).siblings().remove();
         var factor = 2;

    }
```

my problem is, the image removing fine but the span which is under that image not removing.

Here is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/72cr4bvk/39/

tell me how to solve this fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are adding `img` and `span` to a new created `div`, you can delete the whole div:

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72cr4bvk/40/).

Answer (score 0):

You add span with class "insidespan", so you may remove

```
$('.insidespan').remove();
```